# "The type or namespace cannot be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Tags: asp.net

Error    1    The type or namespace name 'EmpInfo' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    C:\Users\Station\Desktop\Test\Test\BusinessLayer\EmpOperation.cs    13    33    BusinessLayer

Error    2    The type or namespace name 'EmpOperation' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    C:\Users\Station\Desktop\Test\Test\Test\EmpEntry.aspx.cs    15    8    Test

But both the 'EmpInfo' and 'EmpOperation' class are there... Then why still its showing this type of error???

Also.

```
public int ACSaveEmpInfo(EmpInfo paramEmpInfo)
```

on the above line when I'm clicking on EmpInfo and clicking on Go To Definition then its showing "Cannot Navigate To EmpInfo".

Comment: if your classes are in different C# project , then add the reference of the project to your current project by clicking on Reference and add the Project as reference. Once it is added you can use the using or full name to access the class

Comment: the 'EmpInfo' class is under Models project and 'EmpInfo' class is under BusinessLayer Project... now what to do?

Comment: simple steps copy the dlls of both the project to your current project bin folder or if you are using Visual studio under your current project , right click on the Reference and add bot the project as reference. More here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3st0d45(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Those classes might be in a different package.Try using the "using _namespace_name" statement at top of the class to include those namespaces. Alternatively, you could also call these classes using their full namespace identifier.

e.g

```
    some_namespace.Classname = new some_namespace.classname()
```

Comment: bw which IDE are you using ?

Comment: assuming you are using Visual Studios. Firstly all these classes must be in the same project. If not, you need to add a reference to the other project. Secondly, if they are in the same project you need the "using statement" to use classes from other namespaces. What i wrote in my answer is a namespace name (you can consider them as packages in java) followed by a class name that you are trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

I think  you are trying to debug code that is different than the source you are using now . I think you may missed any other dlls to support your project check once if you missed add the reference and rebuild the application the problem may resolve .

Or

Add the proper missed EmpOperation namespaces in .cs page and check once